# Inconsistencies on notification banner themes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, dark-mode, banner

I realized that the new "[...] Code of Conduct" banner on the SO site is displayed using a light theme, even if the website is displayed using the dark theme:

[image: Example screenshot light theme banner]

---

But on the Stack Overflow meta website, the banner is showing using the dark theme even if the website is using a light theme:

[image: Example screenshot dark theme banner]

---

My browser is using the operating system setting, which is set to a dark theme on my computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The banner is the same on SO & Meta, when both are rendered in light mode:

[image]

I'm assuming the banner being light in dark mode is to make sure there's enough contrast to make the banner actually draw attention.

Comment: I'm talking about [this banner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJxI9.png), which is light on the dark theme on SO, and dark on the light theme on meta.

Comment: @sodimel that's the same one in Cerbrus's screenshots.  It's dark in the light theme on *both* main and meta.  It's also light in the dark theme, which only exists on main.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I didn't saw the small banner without clicking on the image, and thought that Cerbrus talked about the "main" banner.